# On Declensions and Gender

Tags: grammar-identification

after advancing on German gramatically as my second foreign language, I wanted to pursue my interest in Latin. Grammar seemed to me pretty straightforward, yet so many to memorize. I'm self-teaching and intend to expand my vocabulary, however there is a part that muddles my mind up.

Now, I learnt about 1st, 2nd and 3rd Declensions (I guess there is a fourth and fifth as well but anyway). Taking into consideration that 1st Declension words 'mostly' consist of feminine ones - and for 2nd Declension same applies for masculine - is it the declension group or the gender who alters the adjective attached to the word? If I were to learn a new Latin word, should I write down its gender and declension group together? Summing up the question, which traits of a word should I memorize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to know both.

The declension of a noun determines what forms the noun itself takes. Since *poēta* "poet" is first declension, the nominative singular is *poēta*, the accusative singular is *poētam*, and the nominative plural is *poētae*.

The gender of a noun, on the other hand, determines what forms adjectives take to agree with it. Even though *poēta* is first-declension, it's masculine, so a great poet is *poēta magnus*, and many great poets are *poētae magnī*.

Sometimes there are shortcuts to remembering: the first declension is generally feminine, the second declension is generally masculine and neuter, and the fifth declension is generally feminine. But these are guidelines rather than rules: there are counterexamples like *agricola magnus* "great farmer", *humus magna* "great soil", and *dies magnus* "great day".

Comment: To add to complications, *dies* can also be feminine.